# VLC media player window is overlaying other windows in Ubuntu 14.04 - compiz Window manager

Tags: ubuntu, compiz

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running on Oracle Virtual Box. Window Manager in Ubuntu is compiz. The issue I am facing is when I am playing a media file in VLC or any other media player the window is overlaying any other window (say terminal, firefox, etc.) and is not letting them come to the fore when I switch between windows. Even if I minimize the the VLC player it won't let other windows come to the fore.

I know this was an issue in metacity but do not know the same issue exists in compiz as well. Is there any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 6):

Tools > Preferences > Videos > Accelerated video output(Overlay)
uncheck this Accelerated video output(VLC will try to use it by default).\n
mark the answer correct if it solves your problem.thankyou
[image: uncheck this Accelerated video output(VLC will try to use it by default)]

Comment: Worked perfectly! and yes, it was default. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, So as per my brief research this is the case for all the Linux guests, so I was tinkering around and read somewhere that the VirtualBox supports X11 output better. So next thing you know.. I go ahead and switch the "Output" to "`X11 video output (XCB)`" and ....voilla!!! it worked.

Now I can minimize the video inside the VM, also the video overlay stopped messing with other UI elements.

[image: Ubuntu Video overlay minimize bug]

Answer (score 0):

This question is the exact opposite of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100231/how-to-set-always-on-top-on-vlc-by-default), but their steps are almost identical.

Tools > Preferences > Videos > Always On Top

Mine actually said "Float on Top", not always on top. You can also apparently toggle the option from the video dropdown. Its not hidden in any submenus or anything.